# Adding date countdown to jquery counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, countdown

Can someone help me with adding a date counting too to https://github.com/sophilabs/jquery-counter/blob/master/src/jquery.counter.js ?

The current counter is working fine with hour, minute and seconds. Its lacking only date. I am not an expert with it. Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I think you can use this:

```
<script language='javascript' type= 'text/javascript>
function showdate()
{
    var d = new date();
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = d.toLocaleDateString();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But thats not what i am looking for. I want to extend the above jqury plugin, so that I can include a date count down too with it.